# Negative dot product

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I got dot product of two vectors negative. Does that mean that I can't form two orthogonal basis for that two vectors?

Comment: What makes you think you cannot do such a thing?

Comment: What do you mean by "form two orthogonal basis for two vectors"?  I'm not sure what it is that you're trying to do.  Are you trying to apply the Gram-Schmidt process?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by not forming an orthogonal basis. $e_1 \cdot (-e_1+e_2) =-1$ for the canonical basis in the plane and the two vectors do form a base which can then orthonormalize to get $e_1$ and $e_2$ but it depends...

Comment: the vectors I talking about are A = 3i + 4j and B = 2i - 6j. Can you please form orthogonal basis for them via Gram Schmid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example: Let ${\bf v} = \begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$ and ${\bf w} = \begin{pmatrix} -1 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$. Then ${\bf v} \cdot {\bf w} = -2$. Yet, applying Gram-Schmidt, you can create an orthonormal set $\{{\bf u}_1$, ${\bf u}_2\}$ with, for example,
$$
{\bf u}_1 = \frac{\bf v}{\|{\bf v}\|} = \begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}
$$
and
$$
{\bf u}_2 = \frac{{\bf w} - ({\bf w} \cdot {\bf u}_1) {\bf u}_1}{\| {\bf w} - ({\bf w} \cdot {\bf u}_1) {\bf u}_1\|} = \frac{1}{2} \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}
$$
such that $\operatorname{span}({\bf v},{\bf w}) = \operatorname{span}({\bf u}_1, {\bf u}_2).$